# How use sidebar position when scoll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 2 column layout. The left column is way longer than the sidebar. I want the sidebar only to stick when its bottom reaches the bottom of the browser window. So the user can continue to scroll down the left column content while the right sidebar sticks.. how use jquery and javascipt

```
$(function() {

var $window = $(window);
var lastScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
var wasScrollingDown = true;

var $sidebar = $("#sidebar");
if ($sidebar.length > 0) {

    var initialSidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top;

    $window.scroll(function(event) {

        var windowHeight = $window.height();
        var sidebarHeight = $sidebar.outerHeight();

        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var scrollBottom = scrollTop + windowHeight;

        var sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top;
        var sidebarBottom = sidebarTop + sidebarHeight;

        var heightDelta = Math.abs(windowHeight - sidebarHeight);
        var scrollDelta = lastScrollTop - scrollTop;

        var isScrollingDown = (scrollTop > lastScrollTop);
        var isWindowLarger = (windowHeight > sidebarHeight);

        if ((isWindowLarger && scrollTop > initialSidebarTop) || (!isWindowLarger && scrollTop > initialSidebarTop + heightDelta)) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
        } else if (!isScrollingDown && scrollTop <= initialSidebarTop) {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        }

        var dragBottomDown = (sidebarBottom <= scrollBottom && isScrollingDown);
        var dragTopUp = (sidebarTop >= scrollTop && !isScrollingDown);

        if (dragBottomDown) {
            if (isWindowLarger) {
                $sidebar.css('top', 0);
            } else {
                $sidebar.css('top', -heightDelta);
            }
        } else if (dragTopUp) {
            $sidebar.css('top', 0);
        } else if ($sidebar.hasClass('fixed')) {
            var currentTop = parseInt($sidebar.css('top'), 10);

            var minTop = -heightDelta;
            var scrolledTop = currentTop + scrollDelta;

            var isPageAtBottom = (scrollTop + windowHeight >= $(document).height());
            var newTop = (isPageAtBottom) ? minTop : scrolledTop;

            $sidebar.css('top', newTop);
        }

        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        wasScrollingDown = isScrollingDown;
    });
}
```

});

## SeeDemo

i have this error when scroll top

[image]

i wanted this style

[image]

Comment: Not a solution to your provided code, but you might want to look into [this jquery plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

Comment: yes, sir, i want example

Comment: Scroll that page, you'll see the black box sticking to the top. There is many other things you can do with that plugin, more specific stuff, so maybe you can use that for you problem. It was merely a suggestion, often one doesn't have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Try [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD)  it may help you to accomplish your mission.

Comment: please more explain?

Comment: yes sir, how use  import waypoints js