# Free-Scrolling Sticky Sidebar Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, sidebar

I'm trying to achieve what is outlined in this Stack Overflow question, without jQuery dependency: [stackoverflow.com/questions/18358816/sticky-sidebar-stick-to-bottom-when-scrolling-down-top-when-scrolling-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358816/sticky-sidebar-stick-to-bottom-when-scrolling-down-top-when-scrolling-up)

But I didn't want to hijack that question.

Basically, I want the content in the sidebar to be independently scrollable but fixed when the viewport reaches either end of the sidebars contents on scroll.

My main stumbling block appears to not being able to calculate the `elementTop` variable when the sidebar is absolutely positioned and between the top and bottom of the container which I have set to be full height.

Full code below:

```
var StickySidebar = function(eventie) {

var container, containerTop, containerHeight,  // container
element, elementTop, elementHeight, elStyle,  // element
viewportTop = -1, viewportHeight, documentTop, // viewport
lastViewportTop, scrollingDown, top = false , bottom = false,// sticky vars

scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
         window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
         function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60); },

options =  {
    container : document.querySelector('.sidebar-container'),
    element : document.querySelector('.sidebar'),
    sidebarClass : 'sidebar',
    bottomOffset : -15,
    topOffset: 90,
},

_updateValue = function() {
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
},

_offset = function(obj) {    
    var ol = ot = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            ol += obj.offsetLeft;
            ot += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return {
        left: ol,
        top: ot
    };
},


init = function(){
    if(options.element !== null) {

        container = options.container;
        containerTop = offset(container).top;
        containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

        element = options.element;
        elementTop = offset(element).top;
        elementHeight = options.element.clientHeight;

        lastViewportTop = window.scrollY;
        viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

        eventie.bind(document, "scroll", _loop);
        eventie.bind(window, "resize", _updateValue);

    }
},

_loop = function() {
    if (viewportTop == window.pageYOffset) {
        scroll(_loop);
        return false;
    } else viewportTop = window.pageYOffset;

    _updateValue();

    var viewportBottom, elementTooBig, topOffset;

    elementTop = offset(element).top;

    elementHeight = element.clientHeight;
    containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
    scrollingDown = viewportTop > lastViewportTop;
    elementTooBig = elementHeight > viewportHeight;

    console.log("elementTop : " + elementTop);
    console.log("viewportTop : " + viewportTop);

    if (scrollingDown) {

        if (viewportTop + viewportHeight >= elementTop + elementHeight) {
            element.setAttribute('style','position:fixed; bottom:30px;');
        } else {
            element.setAttribute('style','position:absolute; top:'+ elementTop +'px;'); // issue 1
    }

    if (viewportTop + viewportHeight > containerTop + containerHeight) {
        element.setAttribute('style','position:absolute; bottom:0;');
    }

} else {

    if (viewportTop < containerTop - 60) {
        element.removeAttribute('style');
        return;
    }

    if (viewportTop <= elementTop) {
        element.setAttribute('style','position:fixed; top:90px;');
    } else {
        element.setAttribute('style','position:absolute; top:'+ elementTop +'px;');
        elementTop = viewportTop + elementTop;
    }

}

lastViewportTop = viewportTop;

};


return {
    init: init
};

}(eventie);
```

I've been trying to tackle this issue for a few weeks now, and it has been driving me insane. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just use css with `position: fixed;` to solve this. And you can use [responsive design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en) for small screen. So no JS is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that will not work. Not trying to be rude, but I don't think you understand the question fully.

Comment: Are you [translating this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25025478/) to pure JS?

Comment: I have tried that already but he is using css transform instead of switching fixed positioning on and off. It worked but the performance was suboptimal.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just trying to achieve the desired result not necessarily creating that yourself - well, there are many JavaScript libraries that provide that.

For example, [Stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) is actually a polyfill for `position: sticky` which is [natively supported only in Firefox 41+ and Safari 8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). Here is [the demo](http://wilddeer.github.io/stickyfill/test/) with all kinds of stickiness you can imagine :)

P.S. At first glance you might notice something about jQuery there, but it's pure JavaScript and just adds a jQuery extension.

Comment: This polyfill doesn't appear to support sticking to the bottom.

Comment: @approxiblue No, it actually does allow you to have elements sticking to the bottom

Comment: Which example? It says it can't in the [README](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill#what-it-doesnt).

Comment: @approxiblue Hm, that's weird, I just cloned the repo and checked the ``demos/demo.html``
BTW updated the question.

Comment: Same repo? That file does not exist [in master](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill/find/master).

Comment: @approxiblue Terribly sorry, checked the wrong repo.

Comment: No worries. If you find another library/repo that solves the problem though, feel free to update your answer with the right sources.